# I use a MacBook and a Windows Desktop and I need to switch between them both with the same keyboard and mouse

Tags: kvm, docking-stations

Somebody mentioned a "KVM", does anybody have experience with these? It also need to be able to switch between them quickly as I will probably be switching atleast once every 5 minutes.

Does anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: A KVM switch really does sound like the way to go. If you mention your country, we might be able to suggest a model that is available for you

Comment: @skippy Im from the UK